# Why does Alex sing "Singin' in the Rain" in the bathtub in "A Clockwork Orange" (1971)?

Tags: a-clockwork-orange

Knowing that he is in the home of the victim of his rape and assault, and the man can hear him singing, why would he sing the same song while he is bathing in the bathtub that he sang when he was raping the man's wife and beating him?  Wouldn't he realize that the man would recognize the song and his voice, which were indelibly burned into his mind as a result of his traumatic assault at Alex's hands?

Answer (score 10):

The [script](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/A%2BClockwork%2BOrange.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjj7tikmaOBAxUB_rsIHScvDrEQFnoECAwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw17Ew2hX9H0CjCj635bc6_w) indicates that Alex is reminiscing about what happened the last time that he and his droogs were at this house. He is simply caught up in the moment and blissfully unaware that anyone can hear him as he "sings to himself", quietly at first and then at increasingly unwise volumes.

> **Alex:** *Thank you very much, sir. God bless you, sir.*
>
> Alexander bites his hand.
>
> INT. "HOME" – BATHROOM
>
> Alex soaks, eyes closed, in a hot tub.
>
> After a while he begins softly **singing to himself:** "Singin' in the Rain".
>
> INT. "HOME" – LIVING ROOM – Day
> Mr. Alexander is hunched over the phone, talking in hoarse whispers. The door to the bathroom is right behind him.

In the [source novel](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Clockwork_Orange_(novel)) Alex isn't given away by his *singing*, but rather by his accent, expressions and use of the word "Dim", which happens to be the name of one of his gang members.

> “Stop treating me like a thing that’s like got to be just used. I’m not an idiot you can impose on, you stupid bratchnies. Ordinary prestoopnicks are stupid, but I’m not ordinary and nor am I dim. Do you slooshy?”
>
> “Dim,” said F. Alexander, like musing. “Dim. That was a name somewhere. Dim.”
> “Eh?” I said. “What’s Dim got to do with it? What do you know about Dim?” And then I said: “Oh, Bog help us.” I didn’t like the look in F. Alexander’s glazzies. I made for the door, wanting to go upstairs and get my platties and then itty off.

Comment: Dead wrong.  After the treatment, he is extremely polite to everyone he meets.  Furthermore, he is trying to keep the man from knowing who he is, as he is relieved that the man didn't recognize him because he recalled he was wearing a mask when he raped his wife and owned him.

Comment: @john - He does seem to have poor impulse control. He's just unaware of his audience and caught up in the moment.

Comment: Interesting, I always interpreted it as a sign that to Alex, he doesn't have any particularly strong memories of this incident only any other, and doesn't specifically remember that he sang "Singin' in the Rain". And of course it makes sense that since this was the most traumatic moment of the man's life he would remember the details much more clearly than the person who probably does this sort of crap all the time... personally I prefer my interpretation but whatever

Comment: Personally, I took it as an indication that his treatment had not only made him incapable of violence, but compromised various other mental skills or memories to the point that he wasn't completely in control of even his normal (nonviolent) behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Glad this question was asked. It really is out of step with Alex's character or situation. I believe it is Kubrick using a blatant plot device for a certain effect. Much of the film's ending has been one plot device after another. The fact that as soon as he's released, he is "coincidentally" confronted by three different groups of people who want to exact their revenge on him is another such obvious plot device. It is interesting how it affects the viewer's immersion into the world he created. By not being fully immersed, the viewer's able to have a critical distance and think about what's going on.